# Servlet-Calling a java function

Tags: java, api, function, servlets, import

I have a java file containing a function. It uses some external API.(I added the external jar files).
Now I have a servlet and in doGet() and want to call the function of the above java class.
Do i have to write all the import statements for the API in the servlet?
Cause i get error in the servlet doesnot run.

The error
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

```
type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling     this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException
hello.hello.doGet(hello.java:77)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.read.biff.BiffException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
hello.hello.doGet(hello.java:77)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: In servlet, you have to import the package of the class where you wrote the function. Post the exact error that you are getting. Make sure that all the API related JARs included in the `classpath`

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli thanks for the reply and i have already imported the class. I have added the error that i got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied the External JAR files inside Tomcat 7.0\lib  and it solved the problem.

Got the idea from http://scn.sap.com/thread/1410297

Well is it the correct solution? 
That is whenever we have to use External API in servlet we have to Configure Build Path add the JARs and also copy the JARs in tomcat\lib folder?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes the the jar files will be checked in the Tomcat lib folder also.

Answer (score 0):

just import the class in the servlet which has the method. Paste the stack trace or some code which will be helpful to solve the error.

Comment: Make sure that you have the jar file in the class path of project. Put the jar file under WEB-INF/lib of your web app.

Answer (score 0):

copy the jar files into WEBINF/lib folder of your project